# What is the meaning of <idle>-0 in kernel debug tracing?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, drivers, scheduling

Recently when I tried to do some kernel driver debugging in Ubuntu 16.04, kernel version 4.15, I come across the kernel tracing mechanism, which is pretty handy to observe all kinds of kernel scheduling and workqueue internals. Currently, I'm debugging the through enabling the `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue/enable` events, and check the output logs. However, one thing I could not figure out is the following:

```
     <idle>-0          [004] d.h.  5149.594018: workqueue_queue_work: work struct=00000000cd480b1b function=driver_function1 [driver1] workqueue=00000000f2ec5eb2 req_cpu=8192 cpu=4
application-name-7821  [004] d.h.  5135.079917: workqueue_queue_work: work struct=00000000cd480b1b function=driver_function1 [driver1] workqueue=00000000f2ec5eb2 req_cpu=8192 cpu=4
```

What is the meaning of `<idle>-0`? Why the same kernel space `driver_function1` could be invoked by both `<idle>-0` and `application-name`?

Please let me know if more details are required. Thanks.